# is it possible to design a complex analog circuit through a predetermined laplace equation?

Tags: laplace-transform

Let's say we need to design an op-amp with very high open-loop gain (200dB) and with a phase margin above 90 degrees.

We simply calculate the \$s\$-transform of the gain equation as needed. Someting like: $$ A \frac{as^4 + s^3 + bs^2 + cs +d}{es^5 + fs^4 + gs^3 + hs^2 + js + k} $$

Say this equation gives 200 dB DC gain and very high GBW and stability. Can one design the whole circuit (transistors, capacitors, inductances etc.) just from this equation? Does such a method exist?

Comment: Refactor into second order polynomials, and implement as second order sections. Now you can work on each second order section individually, at least it's a simpler problem.

Answer (score 6):

Write the Laplace TF equation in controller canonical form, then draw the primitive block diagram (in your case there will be five blocks in the forward path, as you have a 5th order equation). Each of the blocks will be an integrator, and each can be realised by an op-amp.

You'll need an additional 2 op-amps to add and subtract signals, plus however many extra ones are required to give the specified DC gain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this is not the answer I want. I know that some circuit synthesis methods are exist and let us to synthesize some basic RLC network and active network(with op amps and stuff)(foster cover method etc...). However, I am talking about a complex circuit like an opAmp itself? Are there any high level methods to synthesize an opAmp or Oscillator or LNA on transitor level? That is the thing I am wondering and excited about.

Comment: @Alperözel We call that reinventing the wheel, and in engineering, that's a waste of time.

Comment: @Matt Young What do you mean? Are you saying that it is not usefull for design? Or it is already widely used?

Comment: @Alperözel You wouldn't "synthesize" an op amp because it already exists as a higher level, widely used block. They're ridiculoulsy complex at the silicon level to get the performance they provide. Trying to synthesize one from the transistor level is just dumb, inefficient, and will perform poorly relative to what's already out there.

Comment: But, someone has to find better ways to construct better opAmps, am I right? You can always use higher gain and higher phase margin for instance. Also, If you are an electronics engineering student, you have to design an op amp at some point. 
Also, let say you are right, there is no need to construct any better opAmps. I am pretty sure LNA's and oscillators don't have a spectrum as wide as opAmps. I am saying that if there is a method to construct an LNA from zero by Laplace equation we need, It would be awesome!

Comment: @Alperözel if known method to create op-amp from equation would exist, one short enough to fit here in an answer, it would already either be in use or proven to be *worse* than what is in use. So in no way you would get better op amps. "Just the same" is theoretical maximum you could get, and even that is pretty unlikely.

Comment: You CAN'T always use higher gain : it may imply lower bandwidth (given the intrinsic capacitances etc of your transistors, it may imply other drawbacks, difficult stabilisation perhaps, or it may simply add expense for no performance benefit. If you could, I have no doubt that 200dB opamps would be available. But I've never seen anyone cascading 100dB opamps to achieve 200dB so I'd be very surprised if such a market existed.

Comment: @Alperözel the problem is that the limiting constraints on op-amp design are due to the *nonideal* behaviour of the components from which they are made - in particular, increasing the gain of transistors tends to increase their capacitance and worsen the phase margin.